# Вопрос по запросам в Postgres. DELETE с LIMIT'ом

Tags: база-данных, postgresql

Нужно сделать 2 запроса:

1. Удаление определенного количества записей таблицы.
2. Извлечение записей из одной таблицы и вставка в другую.

В случае с обычной выборкой нужных значений в документации рекомендуется использовать `LIMIT` и выглядит это так:

```
SELECT * FROM  tab.name LIMIT 10 (например 10);
```

Это работает, но в случае с удалением - не работает, вставка тоже:

```
SELECT * FROM tab.name LIMIT 10;
INSERT INTO tab.name1 (SELECT FROM tab.name2 LIMIT 10);
```

Как правильно написать запрос,чтобы реализовать данные условия?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DELETE с лимитом:

```
DELETE FROM tablename WHERE primary_key IN (
    SELECT primary_key
    FROM tablename
    ORDER BY somefield
    LIMIT 10
    FOR UPDATE
)
```

Копирование в другую таблицу:

```
INSERT INTO tablename (/*columns*/)
    SELECT /*data for columns*/ FROM tablename2
    ORDER BY somefield
    LIMIT 10
```

Если надо перенести данные в другую таблицу, т.е. в одной удалить и вставить в другую, то это можно сделать одним CTE, например так:

```
WITH move_data AS (
    SELECT primary_key  /* и какие ещё нужны данные */
    FROM tablename
    ORDER BY somefield
    LIMIT 10
    FOR UPDATE
), delete_old AS (
    DELETE FROM tablename WHERE primary_key IN (
        SELECT primary_key FROM move_data
    )
)
INSERT INTO tablename (/*columns*/)
    SELECT /*data for columns*/ FROM move_data
```